# Single Sign On (SSO) with Active Directory (AD)

Tags: users

I have some issues with the single sign on option from LDAP.
Currently it is possible that users can manually login on the website based on their AD credentials. This works with the LDAP module.

But whenever I enable Automated single sign on I get different problems.
I also enabled windows verification in my ISS.

problems i encountered
 - cannot find map /user/login/sso
 - when i try with other pc www.(myip)?q=/user/login/sso i get the error 
" you were not authenticated by the server, use your credentials  below".

How do I make so it log's a user from the AD auto in ?

[image]

additional details:
 drupal 7.43
IIS 
i test locally and with other computer in same network

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?